# Making sense of $2{\rm grad}(\langle H,H\rangle) + 4 {\rm trace}(A_{DH}) = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm reading the paper [*Classification of marginally trapped Lorentzian flat surfaces in $\mathbb{E}^4_2$ and its applications to biharmonic surfaces*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256759107_Classification_of_marginally_trapped_Lorentzian_flat_surfaces_in_E24_and_its_application_to_biharmonic_surfaces) by B. Y. Chen. Then we have

> **Lemma 2.1.** Let $L\colon M \to \mathbb{E}^4_2$ be an isometric immersion of a Lorentzian surface $M$ into $\mathbb{E}^4_2$. Then the immersion is biharmonic if and only if, with respect to a pseudo-orthonormal frame satisfying (2.11), the mean curvature vector $H$ of $L$ satisfies $$\triangle^D H = h(e_1, A_He_2) + h(e_2, A_He_1) \quad\mbox{and}\quad 2{\rm grad}(\langle H,H\rangle) + 4 {\rm trace}(A_{DH}) = 0,$$where $\triangle^D$ is the Laplace operator associated with the normal connection $D$, i.e., $$\triangle^D = D_{e_1}D_{e_2} + D_{e_2}D_{e_2} - D_{\nabla_{e_2}e_1} - D_{\nabla_{e_1}e_2}.$$

I do not understand the equation $$2{\rm grad}(\langle H,H\rangle) + 4 {\rm trace}(A_{DH}) = 0.$$Clearly ${\rm grad}(\langle H,H\rangle)$ is a smooth vector field along the isometric immersion $L$, but as far as I am concerned, ${\rm trace}(A_{DH})$ is a smooth function. So that sum does not even compile in my head. What does the author mean?

Comment: What are $h,A_H,A_{DH}?$

Comment: In this paper $h$ denotes the second fundamental form of the immersion, $A_H$ denotes the shape operator associated to $H$ and I think $A_{DH}$ would mean the map taking a vector field $X$ to $A_{D_XH}$

Comment: @Anthony I got it! See my own answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted in page 270 of Chen's *Total Mean Curvature and Submanifolds of Finite Type* (World Scientific, 1978). He regards $A_{DH}$ as a $(1,2)$-tensor, defined by $$A_{DH}(X,Y) \doteq A_{D_XH}(Y).$$Taking the trace gives a $(1,0)$-tensor or, in other words, a vector field. So summing that with ${\rm grad}\langle H,H\rangle$ makes sense.